# How to reinstall Odoo 9 on ubuntu 14.04-Existing odoo installation showing internal error?

Tags: ubuntu, odoo, ubuntu-14.04, odoo-9

Can you please guide me how to reinstall odoo 9 as when installed its giving internal error. I followed the instruction from this tutorial:
https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/install-odoo-9-erp-on-ubuntu-14-04

Tried accessing through http://127.0.0.1:8069/ but showing internal error..

please help...

Comment: I get the same error, but using odoo in Windows. When I tried to reinstall it, then I can't access. This problem is caused by postgreSql, you need to uninstall it  first, then try to install odoo again. Hope this will help you

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No..eroors.. But when tried to access url..its showing internal error... @bhanukiran

Comment: @kamel I removed postgre.. How to remove odoo9 from ubuntu any idea?

Comment: can u see the log file and reply what is the error it is printing there?

Comment: No module named web kanban
2016-02-22 13:26:20,052 4594 ERROR ? openerp.service.server: Failed to load server-wide module `web_kanban`.
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 825, in load_server_wide_modules
    openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 324, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 60, in load_module
    f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named web_kanban

Comment: Are you installing in windows or linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do is  by referring the Official site...
First install Postgresql into your system by typing

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

After this Login as root user in the terminal by typing

```
sudo su
```

then Just give commands like this

```
# wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
# echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/9.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt-get update && apt-get install odoo
```

Now open your browser & check by entering the url:
http://localhost:8069